# TRN file is very big

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, log-shipping

We had a maintenance plan on our SQL server 2000 database with log shipping from main server to standby server. We had to disable the plan due to disk space issues. After resolving that we did a log backup and enabled the plan, but now the initial trn file being created is huge and we had to stop the job in the middle as it was going towards low disk space again. We didn't do any index rebuild, what could be the cause of trn file getting so big?

We also have an archive server (SQL server 2012), which runs an SSIS module, which copies certain data across and deletes it from main server, could that be related to this? The archive did bloat the main transaction log file (.ldf) but after running the aforementioned log backup the percentage of log space used was reduced and the LDF is not growing anymore for now. The LDF file itself is pretty big.

Comment: what a question? after backup your ldf usage is about 0%. make shrink database to get small ldf.

Comment: Shrinking would require backup database to set to simple recovery mode, and I don't want to do that, so there is no work around that?

Comment: i can't be sure for 2012, but in 2008 server it works without changing mode

Comment: We are using 2000 :(